# VHDL compiler and simulator for Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, compiler

I am searching for good VHDL compiler and simulator. Which packages do I need to install? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are looking for a "free" compiler and simulator?
And you are looking to target an FPGA design?

I have had good luck with Xilinx ISE which supports Linux and has a pretty good reference manual so you can run via command line if you prefer.  This includes the ISim simulator which works fairly well, and has all the tools you would need with it.

Xilinx offers the ISE "free" but they basically degrade performance after you reach a specific design size.  There are full open source options available also, take a look at GHDL.

However if you are looking to target a specific device you may want to see what the vendor offers; Xilinx ISE is obviously targed for Xilinx devices, Altera offers a free version of Quartus etc.

If you are willing to put some money into your development there are a host of Linux friendly vendor independent software available, check out Mentor Modelsim or Synopsys.